# Selenium WebDriver without a Test Runner?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, test-framework

I'm not sure if this question is going to be closed due to it being too novice but I thought I'll give this a shot anyway.

I am currently working on a Selenium Automation framework which, though seemingly well built, is running it's code by spawning threads. (The framework is proprietary so I'm unable to share the code)

This framework instead of using a Test Framework like JUnit or TestNG to run "Tests", uses a threaded approach to run. aka, the methods that read datasheet, instantate and execute the Drivers, report the results etc. them are executed by starting a thread, the class of which is instantiated at various places in the code on runtime.

My concern is: though it runs fine locally with providing the reports and what have you, what it would be unable to do, due to it not operating using a Test Runner, it's unable pass or fail a "Test".
Therefore, on putting this up on a build pipeline, "Test"s wouldn't be executed as there are no "tests" so to speak, thereby making it making it lose it's juice on CI/CD as far as reporting of build pipeline success or failure is concerned.

Am I justified/unjustified in my concerns? Why? And is there a workaround for this? At what ROI?

Resources or links shall be welcomed and beer shall be owed!! :-)

Cheers,

- Danesh

Comment: You should ask yourself - why do you have a framework like this? `JUnit` and `TestNG` also use threads and spawn them according to the configuration. What's the reason you did not use commonly used tool but decided to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Like I said, the framework's proprietary so I'm as stumped as you.

Any Java program spawns atleast one thread but I think what I'm more curious about is what makes a 'test' framework tick in a dev pipeline such that it knows a build has completed/failed because 'tests' have passed/failed.

Comment: For the CI/CD tools - they have `Maven` integration. Maven has 2 plugins to run tests. The results are parsed by CI/CD tools to retrieve information about failures. Same for known testing frameworks like `JUnit`. Most of the time, if you want to write your own solution, you extend/implement interfaces from existing frameworks to create your own logic.

Comment: From what I understand any test result has to be in a specific format in order for a CI/CD tool to pickup and report the build status. Would you happen to know if a test failure is an internally generated exception stack? If that is the case, I'm gravy :-)

Comment: Never dug that deep so I can't help you. I would ASSUME that CI/CD tools check for Exceptions thrown and verify if exception is an AssertionException or not. If it's assertion - then it's failure. If exception is other kind - error

Comment: Thank you for your assistance and if you're ever in Mumbai, India, do hit me up for a beer!! :-)

Comment: Thank you for the invitation. I'll let you know :D